# From where does "vagrant up" know which machine to power up

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I have machine #1 running fine and `vagrantfile` is in main folder.

Now I want to create a new copy of that machine for testing.

So I copy the main folder to `main2` and change the vagrantfile with

1. Different IP
2. Different VM name
3. Different Hostname

Now when I run `vagrant up` it boots my old machine rather than creating new one

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Stack Overflow topic may include an answer to your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104830/how-to-switch-vagrant-virtual-machine